# How to create a memory-mapped file in Python that is accessible from a called application?

Tags: python, memory-mapped-files

Ok, I realize the title probably wasn't that clear. I'll clarify here and hope someone can help with a better title.

I'm opening a compressed file (tarball or similar) in python and reading some of the contents. One of the enclosed files is quite large (about 200GB, mostly zeros). Since the python tarfile module gives me file-handle like objects, I can generally use them as if I opened the file in the archive with out ever fully decompressing the enclosed file.

Unfortunately, I have to do some processing on this enclosed file using a 3rd party tool that I can't modify. This 3rd party tool only operates on files that are on disk. It won't take input from stdin.

What I do now is extract the entire 200 GB (mostly zeros) file to the disk for further processing. Obviously, this takes a while.

What I'd like to do is (using python if possible) make a "file" on disk that maps back to the "file handle" from the tarfile module in python. I could then pass this "file" to my 3rd party tool and go from there.

My target OS is linux (though a solution that also works on OSX would be nice). I don't care about working on Windows.

**Edits**

- External tool takes a filename (or full path) as a parameter. It prints out data to stdout (which python reads)
- I've gotten a setup using sparse files working. While not as fast as I had hoped, it is significantly faster than it was before.

Comment: If everything else fails, wouldn't it be a usable workaround to write a sparse temporary file? Then it wouldn't take up a lot of space and likely be faster, too.

Comment: How is 3rd party tool called (what are input parameters/options)?

Comment: You can extract a member of the tarball as a file-like object, using `TarFile.extractfile()`. This gives a Pythonic file interface to the member file, which you can call standard methods like `read()`, `seek()`, `fileno()` etc. Will that work?

Comment: blubberdiblub: A sparse file sounds like it may work. My initial googling has lead me to oracle specific stuff though. Can you point me to a guide (ideally a python guide). Sounds like it may make a good answer.

Comment: bnaecker: I can do that much now. Unfortunately, that only gets me access to the file in my python application. I need to be able to open it from disk in the 3rd party binary executable. That means I need something that looks like a real file on the disk to another application.

Comment: @Elros Ahh, I didn't realize the 3rd party tool is a standalone binary executable, not a Python module/package.

Comment: @Elros Does the tool need to know the full size of the file before it can start processing? What about having the Python process dump the extracted member to a FIFO (named pipe), and then giving that path to the 3rd party executable? This potentially avoids writing out the whole object to a temporary file, but might add other complexity (full file-size issue).

Comment: @Elros basically you need to detect long runs of null bytes in the file and for those runs, instead of writing out data explicitly you seek to the new position (where writing is resumed next time you use write()). The OS then creates a hole in the file where you skipped over, which, when read back later, will yield null bytes. To be on the safe side, you should likely use `os.open`, `os.lseek`, `os.write` and `os.close`, as I'm not sure if the higher level file objects support creating holes.

Comment: If a program won't accept data from `stdin` it may be that it simply wasn't designed to read from `stdin`. In that case you can make it read stdin by passing `/dev/stdin` as the file name. However, my guess is that your external tool needs random access to the file it processes, so it won't work with `/dev/stdin` because (obviously) you can't `seek` in a stream.

Comment: I assume you're doing this on a 64 bit system, since memory-mapping on a 32 bit system won't handle a file larger than the 32 bit addressable space. An alternative strategy to memory-mapping is to untar your data to a sparse file in a RAM disk. Because it's sparse it won't consume 200 GB of RAM.

Comment: Another way of creating the sparse file is to memory map the 200 GB output file, then only write in places that are non-zero. It will also cause less system calls. However, you'd have a **file**, not "file"; and this is a good thing because the OS can readily page in / out as it needs.